# How to add an image to a Frame with a grid?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, grid, frame

I'm trying to add an image to the top frame so the image appears above the Label Frame, but for some reason, I can't get it to appear. The code will run but I never get the image to display once the GUI starts up. Please help.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
```

class Calc(tk.Tk):

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):


    tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,default='smile.ico')
    tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Name")

    frame = tk.Frame(self,width = 50,height = 50,pady =3)
    frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

    label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self,text = "Calculator",width = 50,height = 100)
    label_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=10, \
                     sticky='NS', padx=5, pady=5)

    # Image Logo
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Hercu.jpg'))
    panel = tk.Label(frame,image = img, width = 50, height = 50)
    panel.grid(row=0,column=0)


    text1 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text1.grid(row=1,column=1)
    label1 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Number of Windows')
    label1.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='w')

    text2 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text2.grid(row=2,column=1)
    label2 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Number of Doors')
    label2.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='w')

    text3 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text3.grid(row=3,column=1)
    label3 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Number of Shear Walls')
    label3.grid(row=3,column=2,sticky='w')

    text4 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text4.grid(row=4,column=1)
    label4 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Plate Height')
    label4.grid(row=4,column=2,sticky='w')

    text5 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text5.grid(row=5,column=1)
    label5 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Laminated')
    label5.grid(row=5,column=2,sticky='w')

    text6 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text6.grid(row=6,column=1)
    label6 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Painted')
    label6.grid(row=6,column=2,sticky='w')

    text7 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text7.grid(row=7,column=1)
    label7 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Number of Billets')
    label7.grid(row=7,column=2,sticky='w')

    text8 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text8.grid(row=8,column=1)
    label8 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Number of Pallets')
    label8.grid(row=8,column=2,sticky='w')

    text9 = ttk.Entry(label_frame)
    text9.grid(row=9,column=1)
    label9 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = 'Divising Walls')
    label9.grid(row=9,column=2,sticky='w')

    total_prod = ttk.Label(label_frame,text = '')
    total_prod.grid(row=10,column = 1)
    total_prod_label = ttk.Label(label_frame,text= 'Total Production Time')
    total_prod_label.grid(row=10,column=2,sticky='w')

    calcButton = ttk.Button(label_frame,text = 'Calculate',command = self.calc)
    calcButton.grid(row=11,column=1)


def calc(self):
    total = 'Hey'
    label10 = ttk.Label(label_frame,text= total)
    label10.grid(row=11,column = 2)
```

app = Calc()
app.mainloop()

Output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9F9A.png)

Comment: The image is getting garbage collected. Try putting a `panel.image = img` after creating the panel label.

Comment: Here is the [doc](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) for @RonNorris comment